# String disappears after clicking on another textbox

Tags: c#, string, winforms, random, textbox

I'm trying to generate random integer value (Barcode) when I click on a button. Then, I 'm checking two tables (stocks, units) if the new barcode already exist or not. If it's unique, the new barcode will be written in the textbox.

**It's all working but when I click on another texbox of form the barcode disappears.**

PS: I defined newBarcode in global area as Integer..

```
private void btnBarkodOlustur_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BarcodeGenerator();
    string _newBarcode = newBarcode.ToString();
    if (context.Stocks.Any(c => c.Barcode == _newBarcode) || context.Units.Any(c => c.Unit == _newBarcode))
    {
        BarcodeGenerator();
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        txtBarcode.Text = _newBarcode;
    }
}

private void BarcodeGenerator()
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    newBarcode = rnd.Next(10000000, 99999999);
}
```

Comment: The first code snippet - in what event is it?

What does function BarkodOlustur() do?

Note, that your "random" generator will always generate the same numbers...

Comment: Does clicking on the other textbox cause any event?

Comment: @JakubSzułakiewicz: the random number generator will only return the same numbers if called very quickly in succession - using the parameterless Random constructor uses a seed based on the system time, so as long as the system time has changed this will not happen. But it is correct that a new Random instance is not needed on each call.

Comment: @JakubSzułakiewicz Oh Sorry, It's actually BarcodeGenerator() too. I 've tried to translate all the keywords to English before I publish the question. That's my bad, sorry.

Comment: @PaulF No, there's no event.

Comment: You should move the `private Random rnd = new Random();` at the class level else you may have the same number each time. You should also refactor your names to have a more coherent consistency.

Comment: @OlivierRogier But, It changes the number every click.

Comment: The logic is flawed here. `BarcodeGenerator();` is called once and, if it *fails*, you'll be calling it only once more. In this case, the TextBox text is not set. Anyway. you'll have to give it all the shots it needs to find a *good* value. I'm not sure what *disappear* means. You may have something else that sets that TextBox.Text or clears it.

Comment: @MehmetAliYassı: the issue regarding creating the new instance of Random has been covered by me & others. But now you have edited your code - I can see you may have a problem with the second call to BarcodeGenerator - this IS very likely to give the same number.

Comment: @Jimi I've edited my code. If it's not unique it's calling the BarcodeGenerator(); again.

The meaning of disappear; clicking on another textbox or TAB is clearing the txtBarcode.text.

Comment: Yes, it's calling `BarcodeGenerator();` once more. Also, if this takes less than 16 milliseconds (the resolution of `Environment.TickCount`), you may have a problem (now that we know that what appeared to be two methods are actually the same). So, declare the Random object as a static Field. Plus, you need to iterate the search of a *good* number until it finds one. You can make the method async and add `await Task.Delay(10)`. Keep calling it until it succeeds.

Comment: @PaulF I'm very confused.I don't understand why it's more likely to give the same number.

Comment: @Jimi Got it, thanks. Do you have any idea about the clearing/disappearing problem?

Comment: The current code may just cause the Text to never be set, if the first shot at finding the code fails. Other that that, you may have data bindings that link the TextBox.Text to a value that is changed by something else, or an event (`TextBox.Leave` or `TextBox.Enter` - in another TextBox control -  for example). Or the Form's Validation that is triggered when one of these events is raised, which may cause cascading events that reset bindings to default or empty values etc.

Comment: Or other. For example, `BarcodeGenerator();` should return an int. You're using an instance Field for `newBarcode` that, apparently, can be changed by a method that doesn't return a value and sets the Field internally. You should always avoid this kind of set-up. Set a Field value explicitly with what a method returns. It can be difficult to find out what happened when method, internally, for some reason, sets a Field that is also required somewhere else in an *anonymous*  way. Have a single method that can do this change, explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some modifications to your code. When the button is clicked it will generate a barcode. While the barcode is not unique it will continue to generate a barcode until it is unique. Then it will assign the barcode value to the `Text` property of `txtBarcode`.

```
private Random rnd = new Random();

private void btnBarkodOlustur_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    string _newBarcode = BarcodeGenerator();
    while (context.Stocks.Any(c => c.Barcode == _newBarcode) || context.Units.Any(c => c.Unit == _newBarcode))
    {
        _newBarcode = BarcodeGenerator();
    }

    txtBarcode.Text = _newBarcode;
}

private string BarcodeGenerator()
{
    return rnd.Next(10000000, 99999999);
}
```